# Client Side VBScript in Classic ASP: functions coming up undefined

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to call an onclick vbscript function:

```
<script language="vbscript">
Sub submit1_onclick()
   ...some code
End Sub
</script>
```

from here:

```
<button class="ButtonGreen" id="submit1" name="submit1" onclick="submit1_onclick()"  />
```

Everytime I click the button though, I get the following in my console: **SCRIPT5009: 'submit1_onclick' is undefined**

I've tried in both IE 11 and Chrome.  Any ideas?

Comment: These browsers don't support VBScript. Try to test on IE 10 or earlier or use compatibility in IE. It will never work on Chrome.

Comment: Classic ASP is server side technology, client side code is completely separate from it.  As @PankajJaju points out, modern browsers don't support client side VBS.  The only places where I've ever found it is in company intranets where IE was the only browser allowed, and now that it doesn't work in IE or Edge it's useless, you'll really need to use JS for your onclick event.  The only place VBS is ever any use now is as a server side language in Classic ASP

Comment: Thanks guys... I tried emulating IE10, and it didn't work in there either.